# Visual C++. LNK2011: precompiled object not linked in. But I linked

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, linker, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to use precompiled headers for the first time. Using command line. Here is it:

```
cl /Yu"pch.h" src/main.cpp src/shader.cpp src/camera.cpp /std:c++17 /MT -EHsc glfw3.lib glew32.lib GlU32.lib OpenGL32.lib -I include /link "pch.obj" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\yuryi\Desktop\C++\CMDOGL\lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /OUT:"C:\Users\user\Desktop\C++\CMDOGL\a.exe" /MACHINE:X64 /nologo
```

But it prints: `pch.obj : LNK2011: precompiled object not linked in. image may not run`. I can't figure out how to link it. I think I did it using /link "pch.obj". Note: /Yc"pch.h" was successful

File structure:

```
 - main.cpp
 - pch.cpp
 - pch.h
 - shader.cpp
 - shader.h
 - camera.cpp
 - camera.h
```

`pch.cpp` is just `#include "pch.h"`. pch.h includes everything needed in project. all other files include only `pch.h`.

Things I've tried:

1. Googling for 2 hours (MS docs etc.)
2. Tweaking command line in different ways

Comment: Looks like `pch.cpp` is not in the list: `src/main.cpp src/shader.cpp src/camera.cpp`

Comment: Well. It fixed this exact error, but now I have inconsistent errors `src/camera.cpp(1): fatal error C1854: cannot overwrite information formed during creation of the precompiled header in object file: 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\C++\CMDOGL\camera.obj'`(sometimes with shader.cpp). I guess this question is closed

Comment: My advice is to go in your project settings and disable precompiled headers completely. Then remove the `#include "pch.h"` from all source files. This is best when you don't have 10 thousand lines of code and / or many large external 3rd party library dependencies. Precompiled headers do not really help typical projects used in academic assignments. If anything they cause build times to increase on such small projects.

Comment: @natovan You must compile `pch.cpp` with [`/Yc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yc-create-precompiled-header-file?view=vs-2019) first, then the other CPPs with `/Yu`, then [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=vs-2019) all.

Comment: @dxiv Your comment helped more then any other. I added bat files to automate several cmd's and now I have very fast compiling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by this sequence of commands:

```
cl /c /Yc"pch.h" src/pch.cpp /std:c++17 /MT -EHsc -I include /link /nologo
cl /c /Yu"stdafx.h" src/main.cpp /std:c++17 /MT -EHsc -I include /link /nologo
cl /c /Yu"stdafx.h" src/camera.cpp /std:c++17 /MT -EHsc -I include /link /nologo
cl /c /Yu"stdafx.h" src/shader.cpp /std:c++17 /MT -EHsc -I include /link /nologo
```

And for fast compiling of source files using precompiled headers:

```
cl /Yu"pch.h" src/main.cpp src/shader.cpp src/camera.cpp /std:c++17 /MT -EHsc glfw3.lib glew32.lib GlU32.lib OpenGL32.lib -I include /link /out:a.exe stdafx.obj /LIBPATH:"lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "shell32.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /nologo
```

I don't quite exactly understand how it works but it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

-> For Linking an Object File you need to Use link /out objectfile.obj. Its the proper Way Referred in the Microsoft Docs.
-> Even thought If You Get that Annoying Error Try This Link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linking?view=vs-2019

->This Page Contains all the CMD Linking stuff
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=vs-2019

You Can Also Use the /WHOLEARCHIVE, This Command Takes an Path to Library of the Object Files.

->This Page Contains /WHOLEARCHIVE Stuff
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/wholearchive-include-all-library-object-files?view=vs-2019

Theres also Another Method to Link Object Files /Fo command. This Command Again Takes the Path Value to the Object File

-> /Fo Stuff
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fo-object-file-name?view=vs-2019

-> I am Adding This Link as I thought That There Might Be Some Sort of Wrong Commands Hiding in that line of commands.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=vs-2019
The Above One Contains the Precompiled Files in Visual Studio and MSVC++ Compiler

Comment: Your answer led me in a the right direction and eventually I managed to implement precompiled headers, but I think it's a bit misleading - option /out is for naming executable, /WHOLEARCHIVE is for .lib files and is not related